# How to loop through array containing objects and array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following data:

```
const store = [{
    name: "outside",
    color: "lightpink",
    position: [-400, 0, 300],
    url: "src/assets/picture1.jpg",
    link: 1,
  },
  [{
      name: "To the Yard",
      color: "lightblue",
      position: [-100, 0, 900],
      url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg",
      link: 2,
    },
    {
      name: "To the Room",
      color: "lightblue",
      position: [-100, 0, 900],
      url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg",
      link: 0,
    },
  ],
  {
    name: "Hall",
    color: "red",
    position: [20, 10, 0],
    url: "src/assets/picture3.jpg",
    link: 1,
  },
  // ...
];
```

And what I want to achieve is to put all link property data into new array by using map() function in JS. The problem is I also have array of objects inside array so I need to put 2 and 0 along with 1, 1. So the result should be [1, 2, 0, 1]. To achieve that I tried this:

```
store.map((entry) => {
  if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
    return entry.map(item => item.url)
  } else {
    return entry.url
  }
})
```

but no result

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with a recursive mapping for arrays.

```js
const
    getLink = o => Array.isArray(o) ? o.flatMap(getLink) : o.link,
    store = [{ name: "outside", color: "lightpink", position: [-400, 0, 300], url: "src/assets/picture1.jpg", link: 1 }, [{ name: "To the Yard", color: "lightblue", position: [-100, 0, 900], url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg", link: 2 }, { name: "To the Room", color: "lightblue", position: [-100, 0, 900], url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg", link: 0 }], { name: "Hall", color: "red", position: [20, 10, 0], url: "src/assets/picture3.jpg", link: 1 }],
    result = store.flatMap(getLink);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `.flat` ([Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)) the array then `.map`

```
const res = store.flat().map((s) => s.link)
```

```js
const store = [
  {
    name: "outside",
    color: "lightpink",
    position: [-400, 0, 300],
    url: "src/assets/picture1.jpg",
    link: 1,
  },
  [
    {
      name: "To the Yard",
      color: "lightblue",
      position: [-100, 0, 900],
      url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg",
      link: 2,
    },
    {
      name: "To the Room",
      color: "lightblue",
      position: [-100, 0, 900],
      url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg",
      link: 0,
    },
  ],
  {
    name: "Hall",
    color: "red",
    position: [20, 10, 0],
    url: "src/assets/picture3.jpg",
    link: 1,
  },
  // ...
]

const res = store.flat().map((s) => s.link)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array and then call `map()` function.

```js
const store = [
    {
      name: "outside",
      color: "lightpink",
      position: [-400, 0, 300],
      url: "src/assets/picture1.jpg",
      link: 1,
    },
    [
      {
        name: "To the Yard",
        color: "lightblue",
        position: [-100, 0, 900],
        url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg",
        link: 2,
      },
      {
        name: "To the Room",
        color: "lightblue",
        position: [-100, 0, 900],
        url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg",
        link: 0,
      },
    ],
    {
      name: "Hall",
      color: "red",
      position: [20, 10, 0],
      url: "src/assets/picture3.jpg",
      link: 1,
    },
  ];

let result = store.flat().map(e => e.url);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`flat` your array then map the flattened array.

```
store.flat().map(s => s.url)
```

Comment: Please do not copy another answer.

Comment: @dan1st I don't see any other answer like this. second `rahul-bhobe` and I answered almost simultaneously.